# How to customize wordpress category page

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website.I used genesis theme. I created custom post type and custom taxonomy to this site.And also created some categories to this post type.I want to customize the category page i.e.http://example.com/taxonomy-slug/category-name. Can anyone know please let me know what changes are necessary to customize the category page.

Answer (score 0):

"taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php – If the taxonomy is sometax, and taxonomy’s term is someterm, WordPress will look for taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php. In the case of post formats, the taxonomy is ‘post_format’ and the terms are ‘post-format-{format}. i.e. taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php for the link post format.
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php – If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax.php."
source https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

so if you have for example custom taxonomy with slug "color" and have term with name "red" you just create taxonomy-color-red.php.